# The phase "A tag synonym mapping..." is not properly localized in the moderator tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, localization

I can't find a string on Transifex to make a translation:

> A tag synonym mapping ... will be created

> [image: mapping]

Origin of the image is [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5961/176217).